# How can i locate a specific class with beautifulsoup

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to run a simple scrape bot with requests and beautifulsoup but i cant pinpoint the element i need to get , that's the eu price of token

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
link = "https://wowtokenprices.com/"
res = requests.get(link , headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
container = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-12 region-div eu-region-div"})
print (container)
```

the printout is fewer data that are including the element i need to scrape

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using classes like that to scrape the data. I might decide to change the classes one day. ;) Also, there's a json feed you can use already. https://wowtokenprices.com/current_prices.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS selector `a[href="EU"] ~ p`. That means select tag `<a>` with href attribute set to `"EU"` and then select first sibling tag `<p>`. That tag contains your value:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://wowtokenprices.com/"
res = requests.get(link , headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')

print(soup.select_one('a[href="EU"] ~ p').text)
```

Prints:

```
183,491
```

Comment: thanks!!! i was so close but i couldn't find it. can you suggest me any book,video,online tutorial that i can study?

Comment: @Haunter You can look at CSS Selectors https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp . But beware, not all are supported by BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using adjacent sibling combinator and :contains pseudo class. Required bs4 4.7.1

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://wowtokenprices.com/')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('a:contains(EU) + .money-text').text)
```